# $ReturnValue in Watch window doesn't work in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, watch

In VS2013 we could view the return value of a method by examining a Watch window entry called `$ReturnValue`. This doesn't seem to work in VS2015.

e.g. I made a new console app, containing the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ReturnInspector
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", Method1());
        }

        public static int Method1()
        {
            return Method2(1000);          //A
        }                                  //B

        private static int Method2(int i)
        {
            return i + 42;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on line `//A`, then once it breaks, F10 to step to line `//B`, the `$ReturnValue` item in the Watch window shows "1042" in VS2013, but in VS2015 it shows this:

```
error CS0103: The name '$ReturnValue' does not exist in the current context
```

Note that the Autos and Locals windows correctly say this:

```
ReturnInspector.Program.Method2 returned    1042
```

Does anyone know whether `$ReturnValue` in the Watch window feature was dropped in VS2015?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that you have in **Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators** option checked.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn323257.aspx):

> You must have the legacy expression evaluators turned on for $ReturnValue to be recognized (Tools / Options / Debugging / Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators). Otherwise, you can use $ReturnValue1.

Comment: What's the different between single and double **>** ? @PatrickHofman

Comment: You created a block quote inside another block quote. That gives layout issues sometimes and just looks bad.

Comment: Why was this deprecated/not on by default?

Comment: "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators" option is grey on my VS 2017, not possible to activate it. Any idea?

Comment: @CageE Stop debugging session before changing the option

Comment: Why should we turn on legacy options? Is there a less legacy/depreciated way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

In VS2019 Community it works with $ReturnValue1

Comment: `$ReturnValue1` is to be used in case legacy expression evaluators are turned off (Tools / Options / Debugging / Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn323257(v=vs.140)